# Detect that the scrollbar of tableview is on and off in qml

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to detect that the vertical scrollbar is visible?

I want to know that so that for different resolution i can change the columns width.

What is happening now is if i have the vertical scrollbar:
[image]

If the scrollbar is not on:

[image]

The element i want to check the vertical scrollbar is a `TableView{  }`

Comment: You can use `active` property: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#active-prop

Comment: It works for a tableview too?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it does (it also depends on the version of QtQuick you are using). Otherwise you can put a `TableView` inside a `Flickable` which will give you the `visibleArea` property, which can also be of interest

Comment: @Amfasis, A `TableView` has its own `Flickable` item inside (a `flickableItem` inherited from a `ScrollView`), so there is no reason to put it inside another one.

Comment: @Andrii I often put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` to gain more control on the scrolling and to make the mouse-wheel work (making an app that can run on desktop & android). The `ListView` then expands so the `ScrollView` gives the scrollbars and the `ListView` omits it's own scrollbars. I presume this also works in the same way for `TableView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with a property that is inherited in `TableView`from the `ScrollView`.

The property was the following `tableId.__verticalScrollBar.visible`, with this i can get when the scroll is and isnt visible.